# getting json response from protected server

Tags: php, laravel

How can i connect to this url

```
curl 'https://feeds.listhub.com/pickup-v2/<your account id>/' -H 'Content-Type: Application/json' --user <your_account_id>
```

I replaced  and  in both replaces.

Here is the documentation that they have sent me
https://developer.listhub.com/faq/#how-often-should-we-update-the-feed

when i try this from php curl i get a default get of containing zip files instead of a json response

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                                       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow http 3xx redirects
    $response = curl_exec($ch); // execute

   // echo '<h2>API Response</h2>';
   // print_r($resp_orders);
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch);  

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
echo json_decode($response);
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);                         
}
```

if i directly echo $response i get default webpage but i echo json_decode i get nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no password.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

should just be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username);
```

Where `$username` is equal to `your_account_id`

And you also need to set the header

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: Application/json',
));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, i get a page back which says Error 401 Not Authorized as a response

Comment: with passing pasword it worked.. so it seems i was missing json headers.. thanks alot for the help.

Comment: i am still having problem to download these links via json in response i don't get a download link but the file name only :(

Comment: basically these are the bunch of zip files that are updated everyday and i have to auto download the zip files running task scheduler in laravel

Comment: Just after reading the API docs, I see that the request you are making above is only asking for filenames that have changed (`https://feeds.listhub.com/pickup-v2/<your account id>/`) . You will have to make a separate request to download the file. (`https://feeds.listhub.com/pickup-v2/<your account id>/filename`)  as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thats weird cause i don't know what their next file names will be. They upload new files everyday. And i have to automat download and read contents and save to database everyday. I will take the changed names and start a auto download but again the problem is that on auto downloading the files it still requires credentials with every download files